# Poker Hands Kata in F#

Tags: beginner, game, f#, playing-cards

I'm a F# newbie, and would like to share my implementation of the [Poker Hands Kata problem](http://codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/index.pl?KataPokerHands) to get some feedback.

```
module PokerHands

open System.Text.RegularExpressions

type Figure = 
    | Two  | Three | Four  | Five 
    | Six  | Seven | Eight | Nine 
    | Ten  | Jack  | Queen | King | Ace

type Suit = Diamonds | Spades | Hearts | Clubs

type Card = Figure * Suit

type Rank =
  | HighCard        of Figure * Rank option
  | Pair            of Figure * Rank
  | TwoPair         of Figure * Figure * Rank
  | ThreeOfKind     of Figure
  | Straight        of Figure
  | Flush           of Rank
  | FullHouse       of Figure
  | FourOfKind      of Figure
  | StraightFlush   of Rank

type Player = {
    Name: string;
    Cards: Card list;
    Hand: Rank;
}

let SortDesc sequence = sequence |> Seq.toList |> List.sortWith (fun x y -> compare y x)
let SortDescBy f sequence = sequence |> List.sortWith (fun x y -> compare (f y) (f x))

let rec BuildHighCard (figures : Figure list) =
    match SortDesc figures with
    | [h] -> HighCard(h, None)
    | h :: t -> HighCard(h, Some(BuildHighCard(t)))
    | _ -> failwith "empty"

let isFlush (cards : Card list) =
    cards |> Seq.distinctBy snd |> Seq.length = 1

let isStraight (cards : Card list) =
    let figs = cards |> List.map fst |> List.sort
    let flag = ref true
    for i in {1 .. List.length figs - 1} do
        if (compare figs.[i-1] figs.[i]) <> -1 then flag.Value <- false
    flag.Value 

let (|IsStraightFlush|_|) cards = 
    if isFlush cards && isStraight cards then Some(StraightFlush(BuildHighCard(cards |> List.map fst))) else None

let (|IsFlush|_|) cards = 
    if isFlush cards then Some(Flush(BuildHighCard(cards |> List.map fst))) else None

let (|IsStraight|_|) cards = 
    if isStraight cards then Some(Straight(cards |> List.minBy fst |> fst)) else None

let (|IsGrouped|_|) (counts : int list) cards  =
    let groups = cards |> Seq.countBy fst |> Seq.toList |> SortDescBy snd
    if groups |> List.map snd = counts then Some(groups |> List.map fst) else None

let DetermineRank (cards : Card list) = 
    match cards with
    | IsStraightFlush straightFlush -> straightFlush
    | IsGrouped [4;1] [f;_]         -> FourOfKind(f)
    | IsGrouped [3;2] [f;_]         -> FullHouse(f)
    | IsFlush flush                 -> flush
    | IsStraight straight           -> straight
    | IsGrouped [3;1;1] [f;_;_]     -> ThreeOfKind(f)
    | IsGrouped [2;2;1] [f1;f2;rest]-> TwoPair(List.max [f1;f2], List.min [f1;f2], BuildHighCard([rest]))
    | IsGrouped [2;1;1;1] (h :: t)  -> Pair(h, BuildHighCard(t))
    | _                             -> BuildHighCard(cards |> List.map fst)

let ParsePlayers input = 
    let r = Regex("(\w+):( [2-9,T,J,Q,K,A][H,C,D,S]){5}")
    let matches = input |> r.Matches

    let parseCard (capture : Capture) =
        let literal = capture.Value.Trim()
        let figure = 
            match literal.[0] with
            | '2' -> Two
            | '3' -> Three
            | '4' -> Four
            | '5' -> Five
            | '6' -> Six
            | '7' -> Seven
            | '8' -> Eight
            | '9' -> Nine
            | 'T' -> Ten
            | 'J' -> Jack
            | 'Q' -> Queen
            | 'K' -> King
            | 'A' -> Ace
            | _ -> failwith "unrecognized figure"
        let suit = 
            match literal.[1] with
            | 'D' -> Diamonds
            | 'S' -> Spades
            | 'H' -> Hearts
            | 'C' -> Clubs
            | _ -> failwith "unrecognized suit"
        (figure, suit)

    let parsePlayer (input : Match) =
        let name = input.Groups.[1].Value
        let cards =
            input.Groups.[2].Captures
            |> Seq.cast
            |> Seq.map parseCard
            |> Seq.toList
        {Name = name; Cards = cards; Hand = DetermineRank cards}

    matches
    |> Seq.cast
    |> Seq.map parsePlayer
    |> Seq.toArray

type Score =
    | Win of string * string
    | Tie

let rec Rationale wonHand lostHand =
    let (|RanksEq|_|) (wonHand,lostHand) =
        match wonHand, lostHand with
        | StraightFlush(w), StraightFlush(l)                            -> Some (Rationale w l)
        | Flush(w), Flush(l)                                            -> Some (Rationale w l)
        | TwoPair(w1,w2,r1), TwoPair(l1,l2,r2) when w1 = l1 && w2 = l2  -> Some (Rationale r1 r2)
        | Pair(f1,r1), Pair(f2,r2) when f1 = f2                         -> Some (Rationale r1 r2)
        | HighCard(w,r1), HighCard(l,r2) when w = l                     -> Some (Rationale (Option.get r1) (Option.get r2))
        | _ -> None

    match wonHand, lostHand with
    | RanksEq(res)          -> res
    | StraightFlush(_), _   -> "straight flush"
    | FourOfKind(f), _      -> sprintf "four of kind: %A" f
    | FullHouse(f), _       -> "full house"
    | Flush(_), _           -> "flush"
    | Straight(f), _        -> "straight"
    | ThreeOfKind(f), _     -> sprintf "three of kind: %A" f
    | TwoPair(f1,f2,_), _   -> sprintf "two pairs: %A + %A" f1 f2
    | Pair(f,_), _          -> sprintf "pair of: %A" f
    | HighCard(w,_), _      -> sprintf "high card: %A" w
    | _                     -> failwith "unhandled rationale"

let DetermineScore (players : Player array) =
    let c = compare (players.[0].Hand) (players.[1].Hand)
    if c = 0
        then Tie 
    else
        let winner = players |> Array.maxBy (fun p -> p.Hand)
        let looser = players |> Array.minBy (fun p -> p.Hand)
        Win(winner.Name, Rationale winner.Hand looser.Hand)

let FormatScore score =
    match score with
    | Win(winner, rationale) -> sprintf "%s wins - %s" winner rationale
    | Tie -> "Tie"

let CompareHands input =
    input
    |> ParsePlayers
    |> DetermineScore
    |> FormatScore
```

At the first glance, what could look strange is the `Rank` discriminated union. I decided to implement it this way so that I have the comparing of `Rank`s out of the box.

Another thing that should require explanation is the Rationale function: It resolves a string rationale for the winning rank, and the inner `RanksEq` active pattern solves cases such as where both ranks are Pairs - here the rationale should return "high card".

Here's a list of my concerns:

1. `isStraight` function - how to achieve a pure functional-looking function that would check if all elements in sequence are consecutive (in regards to a discriminated union type)?
2. `IsStraight`, `IsFlush`, `IsStraightFlush` active patterns, these three feel like they have something in common - could they be somehow merged into one active pattern?
3. `DetermineScore` function - I don't like usage of `Array.min` and max for getting a lower and higher value from a pair of values - is there a one-liner for this? i.e something returning a  tuple `Player` * `Player`?

Any other comments about the code will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 6):

I like this! Your use of discriminated unions and active patterns is quite elegant, I think. (Although exploiting that `compare` on discriminated unions does what it does seems a bit of a hack–although I have a hard time justifying that sentiment.)

As to your concerns:

1. Here is a manual way to do it functionally (replace the `let flag ... flag.Value` with this):

   ```
   let rec check = function 
           | x :: y :: zs -> compare x y <> -1 && check (y :: zs) 
           | [x] -> true
           | _ -> false
   check figs
   ```

   For more on this style, see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Pattern_Matching_Basics). Alternatively, you could try to use combinators. If you're willing to compare only sequences of five cards, then maybe like this?

   ```
   List.toSeq cards |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.toList 
       |> function
          | [x;_;_;_;y] -> compare x y = -4
          | _ -> false
   ```
2. I think these are fine. I don't think you should try to factor out the redundant looking `BuildHighCard(cards |> List.map fst)`.  I think if you did, you'd clutter your program rather than make it more readable. As it is, it's perfectly clear what's going on, yes?
3. Yes:

   ```
   let winner, loser = Array.max players, Array.min players
   ```

But maybe already `ParsePlayers` return a tuple instead of an array?

Minor suggestion: You could implement `SortDesc` and `SortDescBy` as:

```
let SortDescBy f = List.sortWith (fun x y -> compare (f y) (f x))
```

In general, when you write `x |> f` it means just `f x`. So when you define

```
let f x = x |> g ...
```

you can cut out the middle man and just do

```
let f = g ...
```

Comment: I think that your recursive `check` is wrong. It compares first with second and third with fourth, but not second with third. To fix it, you could change the recursive call to `check (y :: zs)`.

Comment: Quite! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The way I would implement `isStraight` in a functional way would be to take all pairs of i-th and (i+1)-th cards using [`Seq.zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370261.aspx) and then ensure that all pairs satisfy the condition using [`Seq.forall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370522.aspx):

```
let isStraight (cards : Card list) =
    let figs = cards |> Seq.map fst |> Seq.sort
    let pairs = Seq.zip figs (Seq.skip 1 figs)
    Seq.forall (fun pair -> compare (fst pair) (snd pair) = -1) pairs
```

(I use `Seq` instead of `List`, because `List.zip` behaves slightly differently and because there is no `List.skip`.)

Comment: I like zipping the sequences. You can write the third line with combinators: `Seq.forall ((<||) compare >> (=) -1) pairs`. In this case, yours is nicer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, there is a `Seq.pairwise` function which in this case will work as `Seq.zip figs (Seq.skip 1 figs)` does.

So follwing @svick and @soren-debois suggestions and using `Seq.pairwise` we can write the `isStraight` function like this:

```
let isStraight (cards : Card list) =
    cards
    |> Seq.map fst
    |> Seq.sort
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.forall ((<||) compare >> (=) -1)
```